# Can acetic or citric acid be too highly concentrated when used for cleaning copper?

Tags: acid-base, cleaning, corrosion

I intend to clean a copper surface with acetic or alternatively citric acid. There are many different concentrations recommended by different sources on the internet. For example vinegar with 10% acid content diluted once more at a ratio of 1:9 with water.

I'm under the impression that neither acetic or citric acid actually reacts with pure copper, only reacting with the oxidisation products on the surface (creating verdigris and so on).

Does the dilution then serve a purpose other than saving on vinegar? What could happen if I were to use undiluted 25%-acid (or even higher) vinegar concentrate, i.e. a 25% aqueous acetic acid solution directly? Basically, what could go wrong if the acid is too highly concentrated?

Comment: Acid being solid may be a problem ;)

Comment: I suggest using commercial copper cleaner.

Comment: I remember cleaning old coins in suspended Na2H2-EDTA. ( Complexone/Chelaton-III ). Be aware acids are corrosive wrt copper if dissolved oxygen is present. It may easily form blue solution or cover of  copper acetate of copper-citrate complex.